# Django manual forms

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am trying to get my head around using manual forms. When I have in my forms.py checked that fields name and email is readonly

```
class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ['name', 'email', 'body']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['name'].widget.attrs['readonly'] = True
        self.fields['email'].widget.attrs['readonly'] = True
```

And in the html

```
<form action="." method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="comment-area hide" id="comment-area">
        <div class="mb-4">
            <label for="{{ form.name.id_for_label }}" class="form-label">{{ form.name.label }}: </label>
            <input class="input is-medium" 
            name="{{ form.name.html_name }}" 
            type="text" class="form-control" 
            id="{{ form.name.id_for_label }}"
            placeholder="{{ request.user.username }}" readonly>
        </div>
        <div class="mb-4">
            <label for="{{ form.email.id_for_label }}" class="form-label">{{ form.email.label }}: </label>
            <input class="input is-medium" 
            name="{{ form.email.html_name }}" 
            type="email" class="form-control" 
            id="{{ form.email.id_for_label }}"
            placeholder="{{ request.user.email }}" readonly>
        </div>
        <div class="mb-4">
            <label for="{{ form.body.id_for_label }}" class="form-label">{{ form.body.label }}: </label>
            <textarea class="textarea is-small"
            name="{{ form.body.html_name }}" 
            class="form-control" 
            id="{{ form.body.id_for_label }}">
            </textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="field">
            <div class="control">
                <button class="button is-success">Submit comment</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

But still when submitting without name and email, got error on missing both name and email.
If anyone can help, much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used placeholder in the input fields, when using POST, those values are not in the request. You can set them by using `value="{{ value }}"` instead.

Comment: I am an idiot, Thank you very much